# VirtualBox: Operation not permitted error when trying to remove a folder from host's shared folder

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, centos8

VirtualBox (7.0.12) running on a Window 10 host and Centos 8 installed on the guest VM. The guest additions have been upgraded to the newest version.

A shared folder with full access is configured so I can access files on the host from within the guest.

"Operation not permitted" occurs when trying to remove a folder from the host. The permissions are as follow:

```
57 drwxrwx---. 1 root vboxsf    0 21. Nov 11:59 .
56 drwxrwx---. 1 root vboxsf 4096 21. Nov 11:59 ..
58 -rwxrwx---. 1 root vboxsf    0 21. Nov 11:54 corepack
```

The user was added to the vboxsf group. The file permissions under windows are also full access. So there shouldn't be a problem with permissions. Also with sudo command it is not possible to delete the folder.

I found the issue regarding some older versions of VirtualBox and it gave the assumption that this issue has been fixed but apparently it is not.
Is there a workaround for this?

How could I resolve this issue and identify what process has an open handle to the folder?

I only found a solution regarding a Linux host system but nothing for Windows so far.

Thanks and Best Regards
matt